# How to print documents of a database using Mongoose 7.3.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently using Mongoose 7.3.1 and have inserted a few documents into the MongoDB database and I am unable to log the documents using `console.log()` by simply using the `Fruit.find({})` and logging it to the console all it spits out is a huge data set of unwanted objects.

The unwanted output is this

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map(0) {}, _posts: Map(0) {} },
  _executionStack: null,
  mongooseCollection: Collection {
    collection: null,
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    modelName: 'Fruit',
    _closed: false,
    opts: {
      autoIndex: true,
      autoCreate: true,
      schemaUserProvidedOptions: {},
      capped: false,
      Promise: undefined,
      '$wasForceClosed': undefined
    },
    name: 'fruits',
    collectionName: 'fruits',
    conn: NativeConnection {
      base: [Mongoose],
      collections: [Object],
      models: [Object],
      config: {},
      replica: false,
      options: null,
      otherDbs: [],
      relatedDbs: {},
      states: [Object: null prototype],
      _readyState: 2,
      _closeCalled: false,
      _hasOpened: false,
      plugins: [],
      id: 0,
      _queue: [Array],
      _listening: false,
      _connectionOptions: [Object],
      _connectionString: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB',
      client: [MongoClient],
      '$initialConnection': [Promise]
    },
    queue: [],
    buffer: true,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  },
  model: Model { Fruit },
  schema: Schema {
    obj: {
      name: [Function: String],
      rating: [Function: Number],
      review: [Function: String]
    },
    paths: {
      name: [SchemaString],
      rating: [SchemaNumber],
      review: [SchemaString],
      _id: [ObjectId],
      __v: [SchemaNumber]
    },
    aliases: {},
    subpaths: {},
    virtuals: { id: [VirtualType] },
    singleNestedPaths: {},
    nested: {},
    inherits: {},
    callQueue: [],
    _indexes: [],
    methods: {},
    methodOptions: {},
    statics: {},
    tree: {
      name: [Function: String],
      rating: [Function: Number],
      review: [Function: String],
      _id: [Object],
      __v: [Function: Number],
      id: [VirtualType]
    },
    query: {},
    childSchemas: [],
    plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    '$id': 1,
    mapPaths: [],
    s: { hooks: [Kareem] },
    _userProvidedOptions: {},
    options: {
      typeKey: 'type',
      id: true,
      _id: true,
      validateModifiedOnly: false,
      validateBeforeSave: true,
      read: null,
      shardKey: null,
      discriminatorKey: '__t',
      autoIndex: null,
      minimize: true,
      optimisticConcurrency: false,
      versionKey: '__v',
      capped: false,
      bufferCommands: true,
      strictQuery: false,
      strict: true,
      pluralization: true
    },
    '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
    _requiredpaths: []
  },
  op: 'find',
  options: {},
  _conditions: {},
  _fields: undefined,
  _updateDoc: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinctDoc: undefined,
  _collection: NodeCollection {
    collection: Collection {
      collection: null,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      modelName: 'Fruit',
      _closed: false,
      opts: [Object],
      name: 'fruits',
      collectionName: 'fruits',
      conn: [NativeConnection],
      queue: [],
      buffer: true,
      emitter: [EventEmitter]
    },
    collectionName: 'fruits'
  },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  '$useProjection': true
}
```

I even tried inspecting the objects for the documents from the database but was unable to find any.

Mongoose official documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/) mentions using the above code to find the documents but it's not showing the documents.

How can I log the documents to the terminal using Mongoose?

Comment: The output is a normal JSON output. What do you consider as "unwanted objects"? Do you have an examnple?

Comment: Edit: I just added the output to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is due to the asynchronous nature of database calls. The find method of Mongoose returns a Query object which acts like a promise, which you need to handle accordingly. You can try handling it using .then() or async/await. Something similar to this:

```
Fruit.find({}).then((docs) => {
    console.log(docs);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```